# How to automate "vault operator init" (via terraform or/and helm)?

Tags: terraform, azure-pipelines, kubernetes-helm, hashicorp-vault

I have terraform to automate the deployment of hashi vault via the helm chart to GKE, however, to initialise the vault, I am currently having to jump on our linux jumpbox VM, kubectl to the pod (which is in it's own namespace) to run the vault operator init command.

I found this github repo with an image/container;

https://github.com/sethvargo/vault-init

Which I have injected as a sidecar container in my default vault.tmpl, which seems to work ok if the pod crashes and has to start back up i.e. vault will re-initialise but for the first clean initialisation, it doesn't work.

Any ideas how to get this working? I'm open to doing this via other ways, ideally would prefer to get it working within my terraform though.

My main.tf:

```
resource "helm_release" "vault" {
  name                        = "vault"
  repository                  = "https://helm.releases.hashicorp.com"
  chart                       = "vault"
  namespace                   = "vault"
  reset_values                = true

  values                      = [
    templatefile("../values/vault.tmpl", {
      tls_disable             = 1
      region                  = var.region
      project                 = data.google_client_config.current.project
      replicas                = var.vault_replicas
      keyring                 = var.keyring_name
      cryptokey               = var.cryptokey
      bucket                  = var.vault_bucket
    })
  ]
}
```

My vault template config:

```
server:
  extraContainers:
  - name: vault-init
    image: registry.hub.docker.com/sethvargo/vault-init:0.2.0
    imagePullPolicy: Always
    env:
     #- name: VAULT_SKIP_VERIFY
     #  value: true
      #- name: CHECK_INTERVAL
       # value: "5"
     #- name: VAULT_ADDR
     #  value: "http://127.0.0.1:8200"
      #- name: VAULT_SECRET_SHARES
      #  value: "1"
      #- name: VAULT_SECRET_THRESHOLD
     #  value: "1"
     #- name: VAULT_AUTO_UNSEAL
     #  value: true
      - name: GCS_BUCKET_NAME
        value: vault-storage
      - name: KMS_KEY_ID
        value: projects/......
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of how we have done this locally.  It is cut from a much larger script so you will have to gather your own variable values to fill out the details. This was used in concert with a Helm Vault Deployment into an Azure AKS cluster.

```
#Initialize the vault and save the keys / root token to a temporary file
INIT_VALUES=`kubectl exec $POD -n $Namespace_Env -- vault operator init -key-shares=$Vault_Key_Shares_Env -key-threshold=$Vault_Key_Threshold_Env`
echo "$INIT_VALUES" >> keys.txt

#Encrpyt the keys and delete the temp file 
7za a keys.7z -p$Key_Password_Env keys.txt

if [[ $Email_Env != "" ]]
then
  echo "VaultUI came up on https://$IPSTATUS:8200" | mailx -s "Hashicorp Vault Keys" -r Jenksins.Vault.Creation@provider.com -a keys.7z $Email_Env
  sleep 5s
  rm -f keys.7z
fi
rm -f keys.txt

#Unseal the vault using the keys which are found in $INIT_VALUES
i=1
while [[ $i -le $Vault_Key_Threshold_Env ]]
do
  j=$((i*4))
  key_index="\$$j"
  KEY=`echo $INIT_VALUES | awk -F '[ ]' "{print $key_index}"`
  #echo $KEY
  kubectl exec $POD -n $Namespace_Env -- vault operator unseal $KEY
  i=$((i+1))
done
```

Comment: Thanks, I managed to get my way working, changed some stuff to do with the node pool/gke and the side car container seems to work now. Will keep this way bookmarked as a backup method though.